# Display "-" if value is empty?

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to say in angular something like this :

```
<th ng-repeat=" o in Odds" >{{o.Name || "-"}}</th>
```

So if there is no data in o.Name to display "-" ?

Comment: Your code is work [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bwh5abv8/3/)

Comment: The answers present a correct alternative, but they don't address the fact that if what you have right there doesn't work, the value actually isn't falsey when you run it.

Comment: so, as mentioned before your example is correct, could you post an example of your data in `Odds` and we can figure out why its not working for you

Comment: As your application becomes more complex, it is good practice to format the data correctly in JS and store the result in the scope, then the html will be much cleaner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your example should work, but if you have whitespace or a function in o.Name it will not resolve to [falsey](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-javascript.html) and you will get an invisible space in the HTML rather than the desired dash.

A generic filter could be used to substitute empty values for dashes and apply various normalisation on the input first:

```
angular.module('App.filters', []).filter('placeholder', [function () {
    return function (text, placeholder) {
        // If we're dealing with a function, get the value
        if (angular.isFunction(text)) text = text();
        // Trim any whitespace and show placeholder if no content
        return text.trim() || placeholder;
    };
}]);
```

You can then use it as follows:

```
<th ng-repeat=" o in Odds" >{{o.Name | placeholder:'-'}}</th>
```

This is then completely reusable for other rows/columns and anywhere else you want to apply the same rule.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kfknbsp7/4/

Comment: what if function return not string?

Comment: With the above code as-is you would get an error. Truth be told, I was demonstrating with a simple example that addressed the OP problem directly. Of course a filter like this gives you plenty of scope to validate and type check your input and take such computation out of your HTML files.

Answer (score 4):

For this case you can use ngIf like this :

```
   <th ng-repeat=" o in Odds" >
        <span ng-if="o.Name">{{o.Name}}</span>        
        <span ng-if="!o.Name"> - </span>
   </th>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could have something using [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) if this does not work

```
<th ng-repeat="o in Odds">
    <span ng-if="o.Name">{{o.Name}}</span>
    <span ng-if="!o.Name">-</span>
</th>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create notapplicable.pipe.ts

```
@Pipe({name: 'NA'})

export class Notapplicable implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    let newStr: string = "";
    if(value=='')
    {
        newStr="NA";
    }
    else{
        newStr=value;
    }
    return newStr;
  }
}
```

Include this in app module

```
import { Notapplicable } from './notapplicable.pipe.ts';

declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Notapplicable
  ],....
```

And use it this way in the HTML file

```
<tr *ngFor="let article of articledata">
            <td>{{article.a | NA}}</td>
            <td>{{article.b | NA}}</td>
            <td>{{article.c | NA}}</td>
            <td>{{article.d | NA}}</td>
</tr>
```

This way you can display NA if the string is empty

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator) as well:

```
<th ng-repeat="o in Odds">{{o.Name ?? o.Name : "-"}}</th>
```

Answer (score -1):

If in Aungular 5 you can use if else something like this inside of a ng for.

the benefit of this is if you have multiple records would like to show : 
if has records show what you have if not show '-'. then you only need  to write one ng-template.

```
 <td ng-if="o.Name; else showNA">{{ o.Name }}</td>
 <td ng-if="o.Address; else showNA">{{ o.Address }}</td>
 <td ng-if="o.Phone; else showNA">{{ o.Phone }}</td>

<ng-template #showNA>
<td>-</td>
</ng-template>
```